# unitisation of $C^*\!$-algebra $A$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a unital $C^*\!$-algebra, we can construct a $*$-homomorphism such that the unitisation of $A$, $\tilde{A}$ is $*$-isomorphic to $A\oplus\mathbb{C}$. If $\tilde{A}$ is $*$-isomorphic to $A\oplus\mathbb{C}$, can we deduce that $A$ is unital?

Comment: I don't understand, if $A$ is already unital, why would you need to unitize $A$? If $A$ is non-unital, and $A\oplus \mathbb{C}\cong \tilde{A}$ is its unitization, then of course you can't deduce that $A$ is unital.

Comment: @Lorenzo, for a nonunital $A$, $\tilde{A}$ and $A \oplus \mathbb{C}$ are not isomorphic as $C^\ast$-algebras. I think the question is whether the (codimension 1) unitisation of a (perhaps unital) algebra $A$ being $A \oplus \mathbb{C}$ as a $C^\ast$-algebra is equivalent to $A$ being unital.

Comment: @Adrián González-Pérez.YES

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it may not be what you are asking for.

When you are talking unitization, you consider $A\oplus \mathbb C$, with the coordinate-wise addition and multiplication by scalars, but with the "twisted" product $(a,t)(b,s)=(ab+tb+sa,ts)$. If that's the product you are using, then $A\oplus\mathbb C$ is unital with unit $(0,1)$.

On the other hand, on its own, one usually considers $A\oplus \mathbb C$ with coordinate-wise product. Consider for instance the nonunital algebra $A=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\oplus c_0(\mathbb N)$. Since $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\simeq \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\oplus\mathbb C$, we have $A\simeq A\oplus\mathbb C$, while $A$ is nonunital.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\tilde A$ and $A\oplus\mathbb C$ are $*$-isomorphic, then in particular $A\oplus\mathbb C$ is unital.  Let $(e,\lambda)$ denote the unit of $A\oplus\mathbb C$.  Then doing some basic algebraic manipulations, we can show that $\lambda=1$ and $e$ is a unit for $A$, hence $A$ is unital.

Comment: Do you mean that the multiplication in $A\oplus\mathbb C$ is defined by coordinate-wise product?

Comment: Yes. (Other characters)

Comment: But if the multiplication in $A\oplus\mathbb C$ s defined by coordinate-wise product, $A\oplus\mathbb C$ will not be a $C^*$ algebra.